# Spring Controller to get both GET and POST variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, httprequest

Sometimes we send a POST HTTP request with POST payload to an endpoint with URL variable, for example:

```
[POST] http://example.com/update-item?itemid=123456
```

To get the POST payload in the Spring controller class, I can do something this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update-item", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateItem(@RequestBody Item json) {
    //some logics
     return "/update-item-result";
}
```

However, at the same time, how can I get the variable from the URL (i.e. `itemid` in the above example) even for `method = RequestMethod.POST`?

I see a lot of Spring MVC examples on the web either get the GET variables from the URL or the POST variables from the payload, but I never see getting both in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple HTTP requests by specifying the method attribute as an array in the @RequestMapping annotation.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update-item", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public String updateItem(@RequestBody Item json) {
    //some logics
     return "/update-item-result";
}
```